# JAXB override @XmlAttribute name from parent class

Tags: java, xml, jaxb, overriding

I have JAXB annotated classes to map an XML.
In the XML there are two elements, that have the same attributes, but one element has slightly different attribute names. The elements even have the same tag name.

```
1: <element name="" attr2="" ... />
2: <element slightlyDifferentName="" attr2="" ... />
```

The content of the attributes is the same and they should map to the same Java Class. So I first made a Class A:

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.NONE)
@XmlType(name = "A")
@XmlSeeAlso({B.class})
public class A {
    private String name;

    @XmlAttribute(name = "name")
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```

And a class B extending A with multiple different approaches like this:

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.NONE)
@XmlType(name = "B")
public class B extends A {
    @XmlAttribute(name = "slightlyDifferentName")        
    public String getName() {
        return super.getName();
    }
    public void setName(String name) {
        super.setName(name);
    }  
}
```

I also tried making additional methods with different name and changing the overridden methods to XmlTransient, making the field protected and combinations of this.
When I create the XML either both attributes are set with the same value:

```
<element name="FOO" slightlyDifferentName="FOO" attr2="" ... />
```

or none is set:

```
<element attr2="" ... />
```

The only thing that would work would be making a second field in class B with differently named getter/setter, but I don't really want that.
It is the same data structure, just in some XMLs the attribute name is different (for no apparent reason), so the value should be always stored in the same field.

I just want to override the name property of @XmlAttribute in a child class, how can I do this?